Why did all my garage door remotes on two openers stop working at the same time?
I have 2 Craftsman garage door openers. They each have a separate wired wall switch and separate remote keypads and separate remotes. I have Homelink in my 2004 Yukon that can control both with, albeit only when I'm in the street turning in so about 50' range. This same issue happened this summer and the advice I got from Craftsman was to talk to neighbors to see if they had recently installed some electronic device. Never did fix the problem but after about 5 days they worked again.
The other day the big door went down in the morning using the Yukon HomeLink but wouldn't work upon returning,  and the keycode remote wouldn't work either. Luckily I had the key chain with a front door key. We have a remote that was  programmed for both doors and it wouldn't work, although once in a every 5-10 tries during troubleshooting it worked, and the small door with a separate same brand craftsman opener unit had the same problems.
It has now been 3 days. I made sure both units are not locked. I tried unplugging 1 unit. I tried pushing button for 4 seconds to erase all codes and resetting... the unit never blinks upon trying to set a new code. There are no new electronics or light bulbs installed in the house. I haven't talked to neighbors and probably won't. Any suggestions other than buying 2 new Liftmasters?

Sounds a lot like radio interference from some new equipment, really?

I agree. Could be new equipment, a neighborhood communication tower, etc. Could even be someone's garage remote under a pile of stuff pressing the button and transmitting constantly until the battery dies. Try holding your remote close to the opener's antenna to see if that makes a difference.

place something on the related control so that it transmits constantly ... see if someone comes knocking on the door

yes all indications are some type of interference.  the remotes and keypad remotes seem to work at close range sometimes but not always  but not at a functional range. The suggestions are to remove all LED bulbs... and also flip off all breakers in the house and turn them on 1 at a time. like 25 breakers.  They also say it could be a malfunctioning item not necessarily installed at the time  the problem started.   Not sure I mentioned this happened midsummer for a week then things just started working.

Seems like you dismissed good advice from Craftsman out of arrogance. Maybe don't.

How old are these craftsman door openers? Do they have a yellow antenna wire? These are the most susceptible to LED light interference.
Some LED lights cause a lot of interference. Usually the older dollar store type.   With all bulbs removed, Try reprogramming the remotes including the keypad.  If you have any other large led’s in close proximity to the door opener also temporarily remove them during programming.
As a service tech, This is what I’d check first.  If it works, replace the bulbs with newer LEDs and see if you have better luck.  The programming instructions rely on you to see the blinking of the light to acknowledge the correct programming of the remotes.
If someone is in close proximity to the garage door opener, you can hear clicks instead. Thus the need for the light bulb is not needed in the programming process.  Then bulbs can be added afterward. You can use older non-led bulbs through this process if desired.   If interference is suspected,The key is to have the LEDs removed through the programming process.   Good luck.

This House is rather big I guess there are 35-40 breakers and the panel is located in the rental MIL apartment in the basement.  so doing the breaker thing isn't as easy as you would imagine... Can LED light bulbs have and effect if they are turned off? I did get a set of  2 remotes and a new Keypad remote and I will try to program  them in a few minutes... These are older craftsman openers. house was built 1998.. I do think I had to change one in 2002. the antenna and program button on the main units are  purple.

Personally,  I don’t believe a breaker reset is necessary.
LED bulbs are not a problem when off.  Im hopeful my other recomendations  will help.
